# Load More Button Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 rows of 4 images, each in its own div. I want the first 2 rows to be shown on page load but the 3rd row to show when clicking the 'load more' button. A row of divs is set up like so:

```
<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64">

//First row of images
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center portfolioImgs">
    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="images/projects/houston.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity"">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="images/projects/sugarland.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="images/projects/stevenson.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="images/projects/phoenix.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
  //Second row of images
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center portfolioImgs">
  .
  .
  .
</div>

//load more button
<a href="#" id="loadmore" class="w3-row w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px">LOAD MORE</a>
```

I've tried many methods with jQuery to load the 3rd row of divs on click but wondering if it's because i'm trying to load the divs and not the imgs directly?

Comment: 1st img `class="w3-hover-opacity"">` you have double `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, add a class `hidden` to the element you want to hide first.

then add the click event to the button, on click, find all element with class `hidden` and toggle it. (1st click show, 2nd click hide)

```js
$('#loadmore').on('click', function() {
  console.log();
  $('.hidden').toggle();
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>


<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64">

  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center portfolioImgs">
    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="images/projects/houston.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="images/projects/sugarland.jpg" style="width:100% " onclick="onClick(this) " class="w3-hover-opacity ">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3 ">
      <img src="images/projects/stevenson.jpg " style="width:100% " onclick="onClick(this) " class="w3-hover-opacity ">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3 ">
      <img src="images/projects/phoenix.jpg " style="width:100% " onclick="onClick(this) " class="w3-hover-opacity ">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center portfolioImgs">
    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="images/projects/houston.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="images/projects/sugarland.jpg" style="width:100% " onclick="onClick(this) " class="w3-hover-opacity ">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3 ">
      <img src="images/projects/stevenson.jpg " style="width:100% " onclick="onClick(this) " class="w3-hover-opacity ">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3 ">
      <img src="images/projects/phoenix.jpg " style="width:100% " onclick="onClick(this) " class="w3-hover-opacity ">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center portfolioImgs hidden">
    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="images/projects/houston.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="images/projects/sugarland.jpg" style="width:100% " onclick="onClick(this) " class="w3-hover-opacity ">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3 ">
      <img src="images/projects/stevenson.jpg " style="width:100% " onclick="onClick(this) " class="w3-hover-opacity ">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3 ">
      <img src="images/projects/phoenix.jpg " style="width:100% " onclick="onClick(this) " class="w3-hover-opacity ">
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#" id="loadmore" class="w3-row w3-button w3-padding-large w3-light-grey" style="margin-top:64px">LOAD MORE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo selector `nth-child` and specifiy `3` as the argument:

```
$("#loadmore").click(function(){
  $(".w3-row-padding:nth-child(3)").show();
});
```

This assumes that the first two rows start visible and the third starts hidden, which you can do in CSS.